# How to get array of same keys from an array of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

sorry before if this is an duplicate or have similarity with other post, but I cannot find problem with the same context as I have.

So I have an array of object, something like this

```js
const queryResult = [
  { token: 'c5WKMXW8QdCFUg4q8ica' },
  { token: 'Othertoken' },
  { token: 'moreothertokens'},
]
```

So, i want to merge those 3 tokens into an array, something like this

```js
['c5WKMXW8QdCFUg4q8ica', 'Othertoken', 'moreothertokens']
```

I am using forEach for the solution at the moment. But is there any shortcut or cleaner code?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have only a single property in the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const tokens = queryResult.map(x => x.token);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one property in the objects, you could take a flat map approach with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as callback.

```js
const
    queryResult = [{ token: 'c5WKMXW8QdCFUg4q8ica' }, { token: 'Othertoken' }, { token: 'moreothertokens'}],
    tokens = queryResult.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Personally interested in the solution. 
Unfortunately, I think my project didn't support that yet, seeing that `flatMap` is supported in the latest ECMA Script, which my project is older and not using babel.

Comment: thanks for letting me know `flatMap`...it seems that ES functions are popping out quicker than mushrooms.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` with object destructing

```js
const queryResult = [
  { token: "c5WKMXW8QdCFUg4q8ica" },
  { token: "Othertoken" },
  { token: "moreothertokens" },
]

const tokens = queryResult.map(({ token }) => token)

console.log(tokens)
```